# org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init Unable to create initial connections of pool

Tags: tomcat, jdbc, pool

When I use `Tomcat-jdbc` to connect to `MySQL`, I am seeing the following error. My environment contains these software versions:

- tomcat-jdbc 8.5.15
- mysql-connector-java 6.0.6
- mysql server 5.7.18

error is :

```
SQLCODE : 0
SQLSTATE: 08001
Message : Could not create connection to database server.
org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init Unable to create initial connections of pool.
 java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:526)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:513)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:505)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:479)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:1779)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:1596)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:633)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:347)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:219)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:310)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:203)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:735)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:667)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:482)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:154)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:118)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:107)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnectionAsync(DataSourceProxy.java:142)
```

Db Pool Properties is below:

```
ConnectionPool[defaultAutoCommit=null;
defaultReadOnly=null;
defaultTransactionIsolation=-1;
defaultCatalog=null;
driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver;
maxActive=1000;
maxIdle=100;
minIdle=10;
initialSize=10;
maxWait=10000;
testOnBorrow=true;
testOnReturn=false;
timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=5000;
numTestsPerEvictionRun=0;
minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=30000;
testWhileIdle=false;
testOnConnect=false;
password=********;
url=jdbc:mysql://10.0.xxx.xxx:3306/xxxx?useSSL=false&useCursorFetch=true&defaultFetchSize=1000&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull;
username=sa;
validationQuery=SELECT 1;
validationQueryTimeout=60;
validatorClassName=null;
validationInterval=5000;
accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed=true;
removeAbandoned=true;
removeAbandonedTimeout=60;
logAbandoned=false;
connectionProperties=null;
initSQL=null
jdbcInterceptors=org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState;
org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer;
jmxEnabled=true;
fairQueue=true;
useEquals=true;
abandonWhenPercentageFull=0;
maxAge=0;
useLock=false;
dataSource=null;
dataSourceJNDI=null;
suspectTimeout=0;
alternateUsernameAllowed=false;
commitOnReturn=false;
rollbackOnReturn=false;
useDisposableConnectionFacade=true;
logValidationErrors=false;
propagateInterruptState=false;
ignoreExceptionOnPreLoad=false;
useStatementFacade=true;
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  
Please take the [tour],  
learn asking good questions stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  
Please edit your question, try for improved readability and provide more information.

Comment: There should be a "caused by" clause in the error message below that one that explains what the root cause of the exception was (probably something like "no such host" or "connection refused" or "connection timeout", etc.).